# Do I have to edit all of my posts when I do an upgrade?

Tags: discussion, editing

I will soon be doing an update on my iPad. Should I edit all of my questions where I mention the OS update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, please don't. Those edits will bump all questions to the front page. Imagine if all question authors would do that as they upgrade their OS (iOS or macOS) or device ... we would have a hard time finding new questions to answer.

While it's good practice to include your hardware and software versions in your question, very often the problem is not completely dependent on the exact versions. That's a good thing, since it means other users can reproduce your problem, even if they are using different versions. But it also means updating the version is not really an [improvement](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing), which is about the only good reason to edit a post.

Comment: This is very good advice. About the only reason I would update most posts is if somehow doing the upgrade was an answer to the original problem. The original problem still exists in the past, but the future might involve an upgrade to get to a solution of sorts...